# Pip installation of mysql-python throwing clang error

Tags: python, mysql

**Problem:** 
Pip installation of mysql-python is throwing following error:

a) Error due to openSSL (SOLVED BELOW IN COMMENTS)

```
1 warning generated.
    clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.12-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.18_1/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.12-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.so
    ld: library not found for -lssl
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

b) Second error: (NOT SOLVED)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/vp/vyzq_s9172xbbhh6mzth7grw0000gn/T/pip-build-y6KQBa/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()
  File "setup_posix.py", line 53, in get_config
    libraries = [ dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith(compiler_flag("l")) ]
  File "setup_posix.py", line 8, in dequote
    if s[0] in "\"'" and s[0] == s[-1]:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   /private/var/folders/vp/vyzq_s9172xbbhh6mzth7grw0000gn/T/pip-build-y6KQBa/MySQL-python/
>   **What I am using** I am using a MAC OS and I have installed mysql using homebrew. Then I created a virtual environment & ran pip install
>   `MySQL-python`

Configurations are:

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 1.2.0 (latest)
PYTHON_VERSION: 2.7.13 (latest)
PIP_VERSION: 9.0.1 (latest)
```

**What I have done so far:**
I have tied following  remedies like:

1. Making sure `brew doctor` is without error
2. Re-installing X Code Setup tools
3. Uninstalling and installing mysql

terminal:

```
brew uninstall mysql
pip install MySQL-python
brew install mysql
```

4. Trying different version of mysql-python (1.2.3, 1.2.4 & 1.2.5)
5. Trying with `mysql-connector-c`
6. As suggested in comments below, solving brew link openssl solves the first error. However I haven't been able to solve the **second issue**.

Comment: I know very little about mysql, but the error seems to suggest that you either have no library `libssl...` installed, or the linker cannot find it. Did you try using `brew install openssl` first? (Again just a tip, I have no experience with the software involved)

Comment: I checked my brew installation of openssl and found that brew in not properly linked with openssl. To correct this, i did `brew info openssl` & echoed the path to bashprofile `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile`. Then I did  `brew link --force openssl`. This has solved the previous error but it is giving a new error.

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved this issue by uninstalling & re-installing X-Code

Answer (score -1):

This is because you don't have xcode or xcode tools installed. Once you have xcode, you can install xcode tools with:

```
xcode-select --install
```